# angular navigate function does not work. the URL changes but actual redirection does not happen

Tags: angular, angular6

I ma using Angular 6 navigate function to route to webpages. However, tried simple navigation to check the applicability but it does not work.

Following is Angular version and code snippet. The URL changes in the browser but actual redirection does not happen

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.7
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.8.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.8.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.8.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.8.7
@angular-devkit/core              0.8.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.8.7
@angular/cli                      6.2.7
@ngtools/webpack                  6.2.7
@schematics/angular               0.8.7
@schematics/update                0.8.7
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.9.2
webpack                           4.16.4


/**** app.routing.ts *****/
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ListUserComponent } from "./list-user/list-user.component";
import { EditUserComponent } from "./edit-user/edit-user.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'list-user', component: ListUserComponent },
  {path : 'edit-user', component : EditUserComponent}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

/*********app.module.ts ******/
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { ListUserComponent } from './list-user/list-user.component';
import { EditUserComponent } from './edit-user/edit-user.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListUserComponent,
    EditUserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

/**** list-user-component ****/

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-user',
  templateUrl: './list-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-user.component.css']
})
export class ListUserComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router) {
    console.log('constructor of list user');
this.router.navigate(['/edit-user']);

  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

}
```

URL changes to http://localhost:4200/edit-user. 
But the "edit user" page contents are not displayed. It stays on the same "list-user" page

Comment: What's in your AppComponent html part ?

Comment: thank you. app.component.html had missing <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you haven't added the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your Root Component Template. This is what tells Angular Router where it needs to load the Component Template corresponding to a specific route.

If you haven't already done that, add the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag to your app.component.html or whatever component it is that you want to start your routing from.

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlet-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: I added as per your sample shared, it did navigate but on the same page. <router-outlet></router-outlet> was missing in my app.component.html.  My objective is like a login page where user clicks login and it gets him to the next page. Could you please share some pointers on this.

Comment: I've added a link for Login in the AppComponent. It will take the user to the `/login` route. I have also added a route config to the `routes` for `login`. Do have a look at the StackBlitz sample. It should have the updated changes.

Comment: Hi, I just forked with my changes the StackBlitz. Could you please share the link of the changes you did. will be a good reference for me. I have updated my changes here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlet-eg-db2st6

Comment: I have updated my changes here. Kindly have a look once. [link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-outlet-eg-db2st6)

Comment: many thanks for the help. <router-outlet></router-outlet> was the missing part.